# MacPorts Software clean-up: /opt/local/var/macports/software

Tags: macports

The MacPorts directory `/opt/local/var/macports/software` is really full of "stuff":

Can all the `.tbz2` files be deleted?

I am running out of space on the SSD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes all the files in that folder located with in `${prefix}/var/macports/software/` can be deleted. Those are the installer packages for programs that you installed using MacPorts. MacPorts will re-download those as necessary when running the install or presumably the upgrade command too for a given program ,etc.

The descripton of the purpose of the directory ... is noted in [MacPorts Guide under Binary Archives](http://guide.macports.org/#using.binaries.archives).

> 3.4.1. Binary Archives
>
> Binary archives can only be used on a target system running MacPorts. Binary archives allow MacPorts utilities to begin installation after the destroot phase and install and activate a port on the target system. Binary archives are created whenever a port is installed, and can also be downloaded from a server.
>
> ...
>
> Binary archive files are placed in ${prefix}/var/macports/software/. The archive file type is set in the macports.conf file. The default format is .tbz2; other options are: tar, tbz, tbz2, tgz, tlz, txz, xar, zip, cpgz, cpio.

Comment: Is there a means to have this done automatically?  I mean, some configuration so that `sudo port upgrade outdated` always cleans these files when done.  TIA!

Comment: It is not clear to me from the official description that MacPort will not need these binary archives at some point. However, from the discussion at https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/ShareArchives2, it looks like these binary archives can be used when you have multiple computers: you do the compilation on one computer, and then you can share the result. *If* this is their only purpose, then deleting them is obviously fine.

Answer (score 0):

Before going about deleting files manually in the “software” directory, I would suggest running the command `sudo port uninstall inactive`. The command will remove all the inactive archives from “software”. If you delete files manually from “software” after that, you’ll be deleting active archives. I’m not sure there’s much harm in doing that, but I’m not sure it’s harmless either.

The MacPorts “install” command goes through several [phases](https://guide.macports.org/#reference.phases.introduction), the final two being the “install” phase and the “activate” phase:

> **install**: Archive a port's destrooted files into `${prefix}/var/macports/software`. […]
>
> **activate**: Extract the port's files from the archive in `${prefix}/var/macports/software` to their final installed locations, usually inside `${prefix}`.

The “software” directory can contain archives that are not active, in particular old versions of ports that you have upgraded, because [the “upgrade” command does not remove old versions by default](https://guide.macports.org/#using.port.upgrade):

> `upgrade` does not uninstall the old version of a port. Instead, it deactivates it […] This allows you to go back to the older version if there happens to be a problem with the updated one. […] If you do not want to keep the old versions around while upgrading, you can pass `-u` when upgrading: […] However, we instead recommend keeping the older versions around for a while and running `sudo port uninstall inactive` once in a while.

The MacPorts FAQ only suggests using the “uninstall” command to get rid of unwanted files in “software”:

> [What are the folders in `${prefix}/var/macports/` for and why do they take up so much space?](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#diskspace)
>   […]
>   software: Contains the compressed archives of installed software. If a port is activated its files are extracted to the `${prefix}` folders from the compressed files here. `port uninstall <port> <version>+<variant>` would remove it from here, but then this port can not be used anymore.

There doesn’t seem to be a switch for the [“uninstall” command](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.html#using.port.uninstall) to uninstall an archive from “software” without also deactivating it first if it’s the active archive. So I assume it’s not a good idea either to manually remove active archives from “software”.

Answer (score 0):

As Rinzwind said, you can uninstall (ie delete) any inactive versions of ports left behind by upgrades:

```
port uninstall inactive
```

If you install a port, all its dependencies are installed. If you uninstall a port, its dependencies are *not* uninstalled. You can uninstall them using the cutleaves utility:

```
port install port_cutleaves
port_cutleaves
```

This only removes one layer of obsolete dependencies at a time; to remove them all, i use a hacky pipeline:

```
while ! yes u | port_cutleaves -b | grep 'There are no new leaves to process.'; do : ; done
```

You can remove all the build-related files (work files, distribution files, temporary archives and logs) for uninstalled ports:

```
port clean --all uninstalled
```

To remove just the work files for installed ports:

```
port clean installed
```

The cleaning seems to touch every single port in the tree. I don't know what's going on there.